# Node.js MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Im working on a djs bot and i ran into an error that i dont know how to fix
i have looked at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/ and [NodeJs, Mocha and Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057016/nodejs-mocha-and-mongoose)
but nothing seems to help here is the info -

the error happens here -

```
const Data = await serverModel.findOne({ serverID: message.guild.id });
    try{
        console.log(`checking if a database exists for ${message.guild}`);
        console.log(Data);
        if(!Data) {
            console.log(`Data base doent exist for ${message.guild}`);
            console.log(`Creating a database for ${message.guild}`);
            const server = await serverModel.create({
                serverID: message.guild.id,
                calling: 'no',
                channel: null,
                talkingWith: null,
                stickyChannel: null,
                stickyMessage: null,
                stickyID: null,
            });
            console.log('shit');
            server.save();
            return;
        }

    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

this is my serverModel/serverSchema -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// ServerSchema
const ServerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    serverID: { type: String, require: true, unique: true, sparse:true },
    calling: { type: String, require: true, unique: false, sparse:true },
    channel: { type: String, require: true, unique: false, sparse:true },
    talkingWith: { type: String, require: true, unique: false, sparse:true },
    stickyChannel: { type: String, require: true, unique: false, sparse:true },
    stickyMessage: { type: String, require: true, unique: false, sparse:true },
    stickyID: { type: String, require: true, unique: false, sparse:true },
});

const model = mongoose.model('ServerSchema', ServerSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

and lastly this is the error i get -

```
checking if a database exists for Vixo
null
Data base doent exist for Vixo
Creating a database for Vixo  
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: database.serverschemas index: stickyChannel_1 dup key: { stickyChannel: null }
```

Comment: I will do @Dinesh Ty

Comment: I love you, this worked thankyou

Comment: @Karlis Kazaks if my answer was useful then please upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like there are already records with 'stickyChannel' parameter as null value. So can you please try creating new records by simply assigning values to every parameter?

try following code for creating new record:

```
`const server = await serverModel.create(
 { serverID: message.guild.id, 
   calling: 'no', 
   channel: 'test', 
   talkingWith: 'test', 
   stickyChannel: 'test, 
   stickyMessage: 'test, 
   stickyID: 'test', 
});`
```